# ua fips enable failed and disable failing with errors

Tags: dpkg, ubuntu-advantage

I have tried enabling 'ua enable fips', halfway through got errors and the dpkg process was stuck. ua status shows fips enabled, the kernels were installed, and fips default kernel loading fails. I logged in though normal kernel and tried disable, and it failed again with errors below.

```
Stderr: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Stdout: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-100 linux-headers-5.4.0-100-generic
  linux-headers-5.4.0-107 linux-headers-5.4.0-107-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic linux-image-5.4.0-107-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-100-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-107-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-100-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-107-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-fips
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 25.6 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 297852 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-fips (1.2.5) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/99-ubuntu-fips.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1007-fips
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-107-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-107-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-100-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-100-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on .....
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
Failed to copy HMAC file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.libgcrypt.so.20.hmac".
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fips-libgcrypt failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-fips (--remove):
 installed ubuntu-fips package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-fips
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

Cannot find any solution or anyway to manually uninstall. Thanks in advance.